# Why does my rig fly away in game engine

Tags: game-engine, rigging, physics

I am trying to change my rig to be dynamic so it can stand on top of the static floor.
I tried all the tutorial solutions and I can't solve it. Why does my character fly off screen, and not stand on the floor?

The file is here:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have all the parts of your robot set as *Static*, thus your *Dynamic* rig is colliding with the parts of the robot, which does not work.
To fix that just set every part of your robot, except for the rig to be *No collision*.

A easy way to do it is to, is set one piece as *No collision*. Then select all of your robot (I used Border select <kbd>B</kbd> in wireframe mode so I would not miss any pices); make sure that piece you set to *No collision* is the active selection, meaning it is lighter orange (selected last) and press <kbd>space</kbd> and search for *Copy Game Physics Properties to Selected*.

Animation showing setting all pieces as no collision
[image: gif showing setting all pieces as no collision]

Comment: I appreciate ur help alot . But what is border select b? i dont understand the last part . And can u show me how to select all and make it all into dynamic without needing to change it one by one :O? Thank you very much <3

Comment: @XavierChoo the last paragraph tells how to set all the pieces to be No Collision. Will edit to try to make it clearer.